# I cannot use the msg command in cmd (or batch for that matter). How can I fix this?

Tags: windows, batch-file

While in cmd or making a batch file, I cannot use the command `msg`. When I try to use it, it returns the error `msg is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file`." I'm pretty sure the error is that im missing a `msg.exe` in system32, so could someone show how to obtain that? I'm running windows 8.1.

Comment: Can you give the exact windows edition you are using?

Comment: Try `for /F "delims=" %G in ('where /r c:\ msg.exe') do "%~fG" /?` from command line. The _Home_ editions of Windows don’t include `MSG` command, or `msg.exe` is not compatible with the version of Windows that you're running.

Comment: do you have any `.net` framework installed on your machine?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`msg.exe` is not available on all Windows platforms in all environments.

There is just `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe` (64-bit), but no `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\msg.exe` (32-bit) on Windows 7 x64 Enterprise whereby 64-bit `msg.exe` must be accessed from within a 32-bit command process by using `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe`.

For details about `System32`, `SysWOW64` and `Sysnative` see the Microsoft documentation page [File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog64/file-system-redirector).

What does this mean?

1. A batch file being executed on 32-bit Windows needs to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe`.
2. A batch file being executed on 64-bit Windows by 64-bit `cmd.exe` needs to run `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe`.
3. A batch file being executed on 64-bit Windows by 32-bit `cmd.exe` needs to run `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe`.

It depends on architecture of parent process starting `cmd.exe` or the batch file which implicitly results in starting `cmd.exe` for execution of the batch file if the batch file is executed in 32-bit or 64-bit environment on 64-bit Windows.

So a batch file is called with using explicitly `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe` from a 32-bit application on Windows x64 or inside the batch file `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe` is used on a Windows x64 machine while on a Windows x86 machine `%SystemRoot%\System32\cmd.exe` respectively `%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe` must be used.

Demo example for first variant with using 64-bit command line interpreter:

Batch file with name `MsgDemo.bat`:

```
@echo off
%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe /?
pause
```

is called from 32-bit process running on Windows x64 with:

```
%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\cmd.exe /C MsgDemo.bat
```

Demo example for second variant with referencing `msg.exe` correct:

```
@echo off
set "AppMsg=%SystemRoot%\System32\msg.exe"
if not "%ProgramFiles(x86)%" == "" (

    rem Explicitly reference 64-bit version on Windows x64 as there is
    rem no 32-bit version. But use Sysnative redirector only if the batch
    rem file was started with 32-bit cmd.exe as otherwise System32 contains
    rem msg.exe if it is not missing at all like on Windows 7 Home Premium.

    if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\* set "AppMsg=%SystemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe"
)
%AppMsg% /?
set "AppMsg="
pause
```

The redirector `%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` doesn´t exist for 64-bit processes, just for 32-bit processes.

`%SystemRoot%\Sysnative` is not a directory. Therefore `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative` does not work, just `if exist %SystemRoot%\Sysnative\*`.

Comment: Does win 8.1 have something like this? I get `'C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command` for the first batch and the exact same thing for the second batch file.

Comment: %systemRoot%\Sysnative\msg.exe worked for me on Win10 x64 (called from VS2017 Postbiuld event. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Copy msg.exe from any windows 7 PC from system32 and past target PC system32 directory.

Work fine for me