# Lua on Windows problem os.executing "msg"

Tags: windows, shell, command-line, lua

In Lua `os.execute(command)` can be used to execute `command` using the device specific shell (Command Prompt on Windows). So, as expected, running `os.execute("calc")` opens the calculator. What I have noticed though, is that if I try to execute msg (a program in windows in system32), `os.execute` prints "'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.", even though if I try to execute msg on a normal command prompt it succeeds (displays help and usage info). Also, msg is an actual executable, and not some alias or command prompt keyword. And if I use Lua to open a command prompt `os.execute("cmd")`, and then use that command prompt to run msg, it still fails.

Does anybody have any idea what might be causing this problem?

I have Lua 5.1.5 installed on my Windows 10 computer.

EDIT:

Here's what happens when I run "C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe" on a Command Prompt:

```
C:\Users\%username%>C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe
Send a message to a user.

MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
    [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]

  username            Identifies the specified username.
  sessionname         The name of the session.
  sessionid           The ID of the session.
  @filename           Identifies a file containing a list of usernames,
                      sessionnames, and sessionids to send the message to.
  *                   Send message to all sessions on specified server.
  /SERVER:servername  server to contact (default is current).
  /TIME:seconds       Time delay to wait for receiver to acknowledge msg.
  /V                  Display information about actions being performed.
  /W                  Wait for response from user, useful with /V.
  message             Message to send.  If none specified, prompts for it
                      or reads from stdin.
```

Here's what happens when I do the same thing with Lua:

```
> os.execute("C:\\Windows\\System32\\msg.exe") --I just escaped the backslashes
'C:\Windows\System32\msg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Also, if I use Lua to call `dir` to list files in sys32, msg.exe does not appear in the list

SOLUTION:

As it turns out, because I'm running 32-bit Lua on 64-bit Windows, when I tried accessing sys32, I was actually accessing syswow64. What I still don't understand though, is why syswow64 was missing some files ...

Comment: `os.execute"msg"` works for me.  Try specifying the full path `os.execute[[c:\windows\system32\msg.exe]]` (this might help if you have a file `msg` in the current directory).

Comment: I tried that too, and it still fails (not recognized as internal command, ...)

Comment: I am not convinced this issue is related to Lua, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30977610/10953006) is interesting.

Comment: You were right. That was the problem. What I don't understand though, is why my syswow64 folder was missing some files.

Comment: I suggest you write an answer so that I can accept it.